# Dataframe object not callable when working Python script moved from Replit to local TabPy server

Tags: python, pandas, tabpy, tableau-prep

I have written a Python script that calls a National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) endpoint with a zip code and gets a list of weather stations in response. The script then converts the response to a Pandas dataframe.

I believe I have it working correctly based on this [Replit](https://replit.com/@mxstrand/Tabpy-getStationsforZip-Script#main.py).The dataframe appears to print to console correctly and I can inspect it using breakpoints.

Using this [blog tutorial](https://gunningfortableau.com/2019/10/08/web-data-conductors/) as my guide, my real goal is to leverage this Python script in a Tableau Prep flow. Tableau Prep is basically a desktop ETL tool, similar to PowerQuery, but different :).

I have a local working instance of a TabPy server, whose logs also appear to be showing proper construction of the dataframe (image below). However, I'm getting a `TypeError : 'DataFrame' object is not callable`. I've also provided an image of the same error surfaced in the Tableau Prep interface.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

[image: Local Tabpy logs]

[image: Tableau Prep Error]

Here's the syntax of the actual script running on my TabPy server - with minimal modifications from what's on Replit.

```py
import requests;
import pandas as pd;
import json;

zip = '97034'
userToken = 'foobar123'
headerCreds = dict(token = userToken)
url = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations?&locationid=ZIP:' + zip
global dfWorking

def get_stations_for_zip():

    r = requests.get(url, headers = headerCreds)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
                     
    if 'results' in data:
        data = data.get('results')
        dfWorking = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
        # Column datatypes as received
        # elevation        float64
        # mindate           object
        # maxdate           object
        # latitude         float64
        # name               int64
        # datacoverage     float64
        # id                object
        # elevationUnit     object
        # longitude        float64

        dfWorking = dfWorking.astype({'name': 'str'})
      
        # dfWorking['name'] = dfWorking.index
        # defining an index converts back to float64
  
        print(dfWorking)
    else:
      print('no results object in response')
      
    return dfWorking

# Note: the below prep functions are undefined until they are on a TabPy server
  
def get_output_schema():
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'elevation' : prep_decimal(),
        'mindate' : prep_string(),
        'maxdate' : prep_decimal(),
        'latitude' : prep_date(),
        'name' : prep_string(),
        'datacoverage' : prep_decimal(),     
        'id' : prep_decimal(),
        'name' : prep_string(),
        'elevationUnit' : prep_decimal(),     
        'longitude' : prep_decimal()      
    });

get_stations_for_zip()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution required two changes:

1. In the Tableau Prep interface where stating the function name, I had `get_stations_for_zip()`, but needed `get_stations_for_zip` without parenthesis

[image: Tableau Prep interface]

1. In my script, the `get_stations_for_zip` function needed to take "df" (for dataframe) as an argument. So `def get_stations_for_zip(df):`. Strangely this argument is never used within the function, but it's necessary and the [blog](https://gunningfortableau.com/2019/10/08/web-data-conductors/) I was referencing shows the same.

Here's a quote from help.tableau.com's article [Use Python scripts in your flow](https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-gb/prep_scripts_TabPy.htm)

> When you create your script, include a function that specifies a pandas (pd.DataFrame) as an argument of the function. This will call your data from Tableau Prep Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
execution_result = get_stations_for_zip()(pd.DataFrame(_arg1))
```

because `get_stations_for_zip` is returning DataFrame, and you are threating it as python function, so you are trying:

```
df = get_stations_for_zip()
df(pd.DataFrame(_arg1)) # and error is right here
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Could you kindly review my edit, where I provide the full script.

The line `execution_result = get_stations_for_zip()(pd.DataFrame(_arg1))` is actually from the Python interpreter and not explicitly in my script.

Comment: From where exactly are the logs? Can you paste it as text?

Comment: Thank you, the logs are from my local TabPy server